# Aggragation on a time range and aggregation on all time in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I was asked to write a MySQL/PostgreSQL compatible single query that shows total sales in a given month by a sales representative (`sales_rep` here) and in another column average monthly sales in the entire year by the same person. The query I came up with so far is as below:

```sql
SELECT sr.name, SUM(s.amount) as total, ??
  FROM sales_rep as sr, sales as s
    WHERE sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
      AND s.date >= '2000-12-01' 
      AND s.date < '2001-01-01'
  GROUP BY sr.name
  ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

You can try here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67c65/10

Comment: It is better to have freshers routed through the MCRE (and alike) pages before they reach the "Ask a Question" page. @Strawberry please.

Comment: @nnn If only...

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. I am using it to update my question now.

Comment: Now that I have updated the question, can @nnn provide an answer?

Comment: If the answer (non window function) does not provide you a solution, I will answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sr.name, SUM(s.amount) as total, avg(s.amount) as average
FROM sales_rep as sr
join sales as s
on sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
where s.date >= '2000-12-01' 
AND s.date < '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY sr.name
LIMIT 100;
```

Please use explicit join.
That means you will change this:

```
FROM sales_rep as sr, sales as s
WHERE sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
```

with this:

```
FROM sales_rep as sr
join sales as s
on sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
```

And finally when it would make sense to order it by amount or average value and not by name before you limit first 100. So, because of that, this solution:

```
SELECT sr.name as name, SUM(s.amount) as total, avg(s.amount) as average
FROM sales_rep as sr, sales as s
WHERE sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
AND s.date >= '2000-12-01' 
AND s.date < '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY sr.name
order by total
limit 100;
```

Comment: Fair down vote, I agree. I was editing... Still am... again... I agree... Thanks

Comment: @LearnerFor-life please tell me what is wrong here so I can try better. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67c65/17

Comment: The monthly average sale throughout the year is wrong. For both all users in there, it will be 50. (100+500)/12 and (100+200+300)/12

Comment: Hi @LearnerFor-life  Is this ok: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67c65/24

Comment: Hi @LearnerFor-life or maybe this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67c65/37

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect, MySQL makes no guarantee as regards the ordering of GROUP BY results. This link sugests the change came about in 8.0, but actually, I think it was earlier https://mysqlserverteam.com/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, thanks for support. inline selects  group by ?

Comment: So @LearnerFor-life are any of the simulations answers ok ?

Comment: The predicate "date between '2000-12-01' and '2001-01-01'" does NOT give the same results as the predicates :date>= '2000-12-01' and date < '2001-01-01':. Between is inclusive of both ends so it include the ending date, where the < operator excludes it.

Comment: We ALL make those seemly inconsequential mistakes, I've certainly had my share (maybe more). Just hope they get caught before turning a minor mistake into a major problem.

Comment: Hi @LearnerFor-life It would be nice to get a feedback from you. I have given you few examples. If one of them works please tell me which one. Also you can accept the correct answer. That would be a fair thing from you to do. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT YEAR(s.date), MONTH(s.date), sr.name, SUM(s.amount) as total, 
       SUM(SUM(s.amount)) OVER () / 12 as monthly_average
FROM sales_rep sr JOIN
     sales s
     ON sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
WHERE s.date >= '2000-12-01' AND s.date < '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY sr.name, YEAR(s.date), MONTH(s.date);
```

Note:  This counts months with no sales as being `0`.  If you want to disregard them:

```
SELECT YEAR(s.date), MONTH(s.date), sr.name, SUM(s.amount) as total, 
       AVG(SUM(s.amount)) OVER () as monthly_average
FROM sales_rep sr JOIN
     sales s
     ON sr.id = s.sales_rep_id
WHERE s.date >= '2000-12-01' AND s.date < '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY sr.name, YEAR(s.date), MONTH(s.date);
```

Comment: The queries didn't work and I am not allowed to return year and month.